# Issue plotting Continuous data over discrete data and then using line according another discrete data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

ID    X    Y    Z  DATE

P1    10   53   8  OUT-99

P2    14   5    2  OUT-99

(...)

P4    14   31    1  JUN-99

P5    12    8    7  JUN-99

P6 (...)

I want my x-axis to be related to the date and my y-axis being the X values.
I did the following:

```
medicao$ID<-as.factor(medicao$ID)
medicao$Date<-as.factor(medicao$Date)

pl<-ggplot(data=medicao, mapping = aes(x=mes,y=C10C40, color=ID, group=1))+geom_point()+geom_line()

pl<-tph+geom_hline(yintercept = 10)+labs(title = 'Evolution', x='P', y='concentration (ug/l)', color='ID');
```

Adding the geom_line() adds a line that it's vertical and doesn't connect each dot related to the same ID only with the same date.

So I tried instead of just geom_line(), making geom_line(aes(x=ID, y=X)).

But it does almost the same thing as the first one.
Also tried converting the ID and Date to numeric and then on the labels somehow doing it as factor.

Out of ideas, anyone?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest next approach. Using some dummy data:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
med <- structure(list(ID = c("P1", "P2", "P4", "P5", "P1", "P2", "P4", 
"P5"), X = c(10L, 14L, 14L, 12L, 15L, 19L, 19L, 17L), Y = c(53L, 
5L, 31L, 8L, 55L, 7L, 33L, 10L), Z = c(8L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 11L, 5L, 
4L, 10L), DATE = c("OUT-99", "OUT-99", "JUN-99", "JUN-99", "JUN-99", 
"JUN-99", "OUT-99", "OUT-99")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Which looks like this:

```
  ID  X  Y  Z   DATE
1 P1 10 53  8 OUT-99
2 P2 14  5  2 OUT-99
3 P4 14 31  1 JUN-99
4 P5 12  8  7 JUN-99
5 P1 15 55 11 JUN-99
6 P2 19  7  5 JUN-99
7 P4 19 33  4 OUT-99
8 P5 17 10 10 OUT-99
```

If you want connected lines be careful about what you define in `group` argument. Using the same code with slight changes, this would be the plot:

```
#Format
med$ID<-as.factor(med$ID)
med$DATE<-as.factor(med$DATE)
#Plot
ggplot(data=med,aes(x=DATE,y=X, color=ID, group=ID))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: First thanks a lot for spending your time to answer my question! Second , thanks for solving it! Hum...so the problem was with the group function, well I have to read the FAQ about it then. Thanks again !